# will a server side rendered reactjs application work without javascript

Tags: reactjs

I am starting a new project and one of the requirements is potentially for the app to work when javascript is turned off.

I have been using reactjs for a while but solely as a SPA javascript app that runs in the browser. 
I don't think I quite understand how a react SSR application works.

[next.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/) is intriguing.  Will a SSR application work without javascript?

If not can someone explain how an SSR application works or what problem it is solving.

Answer (score 4):

SSR means the server will render the initial state of the application before sending it to the client on the initial run. This makes it so that:

1. Crawlers see actual content and can index your site based on it.
2. In most cases it speeds up your application since it puts the responsibility of the initial request on the server which is usually faster than most commercial computers

An SSR cannot work without javascript. It'll render initially but then subsequent executions and state changes will not be possible. 
I suppose if your application doesn't require any subsequent state changes or provide further functionalities after the first load then it wouldn't need javascript.

Comment: Actually most crawlers render JS now. Or at the very least google does. https://www.google.com/amp/searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157/amp

Comment: I know google does but it's still a bonafide reason since not all crawlers do

Comment: what about next.js, they claim an app created with their framework will work without js